Route handler throws error 500 when fetching API within the app
I created a sample route for my route handler with such simple structure:
api
└── readItems
    └── route.js

the route.js itself, just returns a simple message:
 
export async function GET(Request) {
    const response = { message: "This is a new API route" };
    return new Response(JSON.stringify(response), {
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    });
  }
  

but I can't fetch it from the server component. however it works fine, if you manually enter the URL in the browser.
I get this error from server:
Response {
  status: 500,
  statusText: 'Internal Server Error',
  headers: Headers {
    'cache-control': 'no-store, must-revalidate',
    'x-powered-by': 'Next.js',
    etag: '"11zryv620o3240"',
    'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
    vary: 'Accept-Encoding',
    'content-encoding': 'gzip',
    date: 'Wed, 27 Nov 2024 07:19:10 GMT',
    connection: 'keep-alive',
    'keep-alive': 'timeout=5',
    'transfer-encoding': 'chunked'
  },
  body: ReadableStream { locked: false, state: 'readable', supportsBYOB: true },
  bodyUsed: false,
  ok: false,
  redirected: false,
  type: 'basic',
  url: 'http://localhost:3888/api/readItems'
}

I fetch the api this way :
  const _accordionItems =  await fetch('http://localhost:3888/api/readItems',{method:'get'})

at first, I tried to not add http://localhost:3888/ but it gave me invalid url error. so I did some search and according to stack overflow, I should in fact define the full URL.
and now after defining the full URL as you can see, server gives me the error above.
note : I write APIs as simple as that and if they work, I add functionality. that's why the response is assigned to _accordionItems 
